# Receiving ExtensionError when renewing mail subscriptions using Graph API for existing valid subscriptions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

We're using the following to renew mail subscriptions using an app-level access token (have been doing so for a while now).

`PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{subscriptionId}`

Lately, this request started failing sporadically, for valid subscriptions, with the following error:

`ExtensionError - Operation: Update; Exception: [Status Code: NotFound; Reason: Not Found]`

For example, the following ID failed to renew `efea31ea-4ff4-4199-8f68-78ec0462797d` even though its expiry is the next day.

For this same mailbox, a new subscription is successfully created after failing to renew the existing one. The mailbox seems to exist and can be queries using the Graph API.

This issue seems to be about the subscription, not the mailbox.

These errors seems to have started last month, so fairly recent.
Anyone encountered these or is aware of any existing issue with renewing subscriptions using the Graph API?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi there, we have the exact same issue, but we noticed it this year. Not sure when it actually started. So are you able to delete the failing subscription? We are afraid to create a new one, so we don't end up with multiple subscriptions for the same mailbox.

Comment: @D.Gencheva - the issue was fixed by Microsoft shortly after it was reported here. In case you find such subscriptions, you'd need to recreate them, otherwise you will not receive any webhooks.