# Error when renewing Microsoft Graph Subscription

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have this project in which I need to have a subscription to a specific calendar. This is done, no issue here.

In order to keep the subscription alive, I have a mechanism that runs a script once per day, which renews that specific subscription by giving it an expiration date that is two days after. It works fine, most of the time.

The issue is that, twice now, the first time in March and the last time earlier this week, the subscription has not been successfully renewed, and I get this error response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "Operation: Update; Exception: [Status Code: NotFound; Reason: The subscription with Id 'M0M5MUUwODEtQkQ5RS00OTlCLTkxNjMtNDdDRUYxODhDMjI5XzEzMjQ0RjZDLUMwRTEtNDg3RC1CQUQ4LThDOEFFNzXXXkNDNQ==' is not found.]",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "b1f7af53-XXXX-XXXX-b38e-750453299588",
      "date": "2019-06-01T23:30:07"
    }
  }
}
```

(changed a few characters just to be safe)

I am pretty sure that this problem was not originated on my end, because nothing changed there.

Upon searching for this error code, I came across similar issues ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55292161/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53111286/7902641), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53599088/)), but some of them are not exactly the same, and there seems to not be any definitive explanation or response for the issue.

With all this in mind, I would like to know if someone can help me out - this is rolling in production, so it's hurting me a lot.

Comment: which api you use ? is that subscription update api

Comment: your subscription may be already expired